# Authorization with pundit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-policy, pundit

User has package. User belongs to package and package has many users.One to many relation between user and package. Gold, silver,bronze are packages. So how can we authorize the user of silver package can add 100 posts per month , gold package user can  add 200 posts per month and bronze package user can add 50 posts per month.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this in the `PostPolicy`

`def create?
  user.montly_posts >= user.allowed_posts
end`

And in the `User` model add the helper methods for `monthly_posts` and `allowed_posts`